# Custom ajax call returns 0

Tags: php

I' am still searching on why am getting 0 when doing a ajax call on wordpress. I know that when a ajax call is successfull it returns 0. I' am returning some value from the ajax call and it returns 0 with it.

Here's my code
Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        action: 'registerform',
        name: 'John',
        age: '38'
    },
    success: function( data ){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

PHP Function

```
function registerform(){
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
add_action('wp_ajax_registerform', 'registerform');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_registerform', 'registerform');
```

Above Code returns
John0

Please help?

Comment: die(); in the ajax function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your registerform() function to include die() after you echo your response.  Example:

```
function registerform(){
    echo $_POST['name'];
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_registerform', 'registerform');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_registerform', 'registerform');
```

Comment: I would also recommend using a prefix in your function name ( example: yourprefix_registerform() ), and using a nonce ( http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces ) along with check_ajax_referrer() to secure your form.

Comment: I just want to take the opportunity to thank you for [bootstrapwp](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/)! Used it a couple of times, never did that, shame on me. Everyone else, check it out!

Comment: Thank you ialocin!  Glad to hear you found the theme useful.  I am working on an update for bootstrap 3, and hope to have it released before the end of the year.

Comment: Awesome! I'm working with a fairly customized and older version, but this might a good opportunity to transfer to the next generation.